# Observe layer 'strokeEnd' animation event

Tags: ios, animation, observer-pattern

I want to observe the strokeEnd key path when the animation has begun. But it doesn't work, where did I go wrong?

```
- (void)addAnimation {
    // do animation
    CABasicAnimation *drawAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
    drawAnimation.duration            = 3.f;
    drawAnimation.repeatCount         = 1.0;
    drawAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
    drawAnimation.toValue   = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5f];
    drawAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    drawAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    drawAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    [self.progressLayer addAnimation:drawAnimation forKey:@"drawCircleAnimation"];
    [self.progressLayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"strokeEnd" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL]; // 监听position

}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    NSLog(@"change:%@",change);
    // not called here...
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if there will be any difference, but try giving context as 'nil' instead of NULL.. Because I don't see any other problem here

Comment: Are you sure strokeEnd is KVO compliant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't observe animated properties changing while an animation is "in flight" like that. The property is actually set to the ending value at the beginning of the animation. Then there is a "presentation layer" that's placed on top of the view's regular layer and the animation takes place on that layer.

The best you're going to be able to do is to set up a `CADisplayLink` timer (a lightweight timer that's synced to the refresh rate of the screen) and query the property on the presentation layer as it animates (`layer.presentationLayer.strokeEnd`, in your case.)

Comment: I have followed your steps, and everything works as expected! Thank you

Comment: I'm calling `layer.presentationLayer.strokeEnd` in method specified by the `selector` of  `CADisplayLink`. And it crashes on `layer.presentationLayer`. I don't know why. The error msg is `-[CAShapeLayer doubleValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x283624c40`